# adding c/c++ source file in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and having problems selecting a source folder. I want to add c++ file to my jni folder, but when I click on "browse" there are no folders.

[image: Example screen capture]

Comment: Do you need to browse for a folder? If you right click on the *jni* folder and select *New -> Source File* and enter file name, Eclipse should create the file in that folder.

Comment: that worked, very much appreciated. Its New->File in Eclipse Juno to anyone wondering.

Comment: @Praetorian Chum, when you know the answer, why don't you 'answer' it? I mean why should you comment when you can answer it. Well, I am new to Stackoverflow that's why I felt like asking, does it give you more points when a comment is upvoted than an answer beingg upvoted ? Anyway, I have upvoted your comment and I am re-posting your comment as an answer. :)

Comment: @Rage No, upvotes on comments don't give you *any* points. I commented instead of answering because it seemed (at least to me) like an obvious solution that the OP would've tried already. So I wasn't sure if I was on the right track, or if I was misreading the question. Welcome to SO and +1 to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the 'jni' folder and select New -> Source File and enter the file name, Eclipse will create the file in that folder.